# Binding downvote to two clicks

Tags: usability, interaction-design, user-behavior, voting

I can remember that in the early days of the current comment system of Youtube, downvote button at comments had no effect unless you had a double-click on those.

Indeed, this prevented, let's say, "less intelligent", **or at least, enraged** and otherwise inexperienced users from mass downvoting.

On the other hand, I have doubts about whether it's fair. It's tricky and non-obvious, fooling users.

In general, what are the circumstances and factors that define, whether it's a good or a bad idea?

Comment: I believe there are apps out there that prevent you from drunk-texting by making you answer a maths question before you can send (one example: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.launch.drunkmodenew&hl=en_GB) - It has a similar deterrent/delaying effect but is much more visible. Maybe that's the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, which requires the person to think about their action and to confirm it, in a similar vein to SO.

[image: Downvote confirmation (pre-state, post state)]

Comment: One can then instruct the user that a double-click will skip this confirmation step.

Comment: I'm with @bloodyKnuckles - while it seems to be a nice solution, it'd be a bit frustrating in a longer term without the ability to get away with it.

Comment: That's a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Adding some [cognitive load strain](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/83295/should-you-always-minimize-cognitive-load) can be a good idea in certain situations.

- "This might prevent enraged users": I am quite sure if an enraged user wants to leave his negative feedback he will do a second click.
- "This might prevent inexperienced users": If the upvote is present and has the same visibility I guess we could argue the same about it.

It depends on the experience the app wants to give to the users voting and to the users reading:

- **If the goal is to have "quality" votes, don't let the vote be easily done**. Adding an extra step (however the form) makes users take an extra second to think about it and know what they are doing. Lower number of votes but higher quality.
- **If the goal is to have more votes then the more visible and accessible (the vote control) the better**. Whether upvote or downvote more users will vote if it is easier. Higher number of votes but lower quality.

---

About binding the second step to a second click I don't believe it is a reliable method. In Stack Exchange for example, **a second click undoes the action**. Rather than a second click I would think more of a [confirmation dialog.](https://material.google.com/components/dialogs.html#)